# Print ajax data result on a specific page

Tags: javascript, ajax

i'm acing an issue to print the data result i got from an ajax call in another page. The code works fine if a print the result on the same page .

below my code which is inside a ready function

```
$("body").delegate(".selectitem","click",function(event){
    $("#get_item_detail").html("<h3>Loading..why.</h3>");
    event.preventDefault();
    var cidd = $(this).attr('cidd');
    
        $.ajax({
        url     :   "action.php",
        method  :   "POST",
        data    :   {get_seleted_item:1,product_id:cidd},
        success :   function(data){
            
            $("#get_item_detail").html(data);
        }   
    })
})
```

Comment: What doesn't work ? Please elaborate

Comment: The data doesn't load on the new page. I solve it by working with localsrorage function. Thank you